Pointer allocation in xgboost
I am improving an xgboost application coded in C++. I am using the C version (the application was coded in C++, but it uses the xgboost C version).
In the application, I find many calls to this function (I put it with its parameters declarations):
char const config[] =
    "{\"training\": false, \"type\": 0, "
    "\"iteration_begin\": 0, \"iteration_end\": 0, \"strict_shape\": false}";
/* Shape of output prediction */
uint64_t const* out_shape;
/* Dimension of output prediction */
uint64_t out_dim;
/* Pointer to a thread local contiguous array, assigned in prediction function. */
float const* out_result = NULL;
safe_xgboost(
    XGBoosterPredictFromDMatrix(booster, dmatrix, config, &out_shape, &out_dim, &out_result));

This code snippet was directly taken from the c_api tutorial of xgboost.
As can be seen, there are two pointer declarations: out_shape and out_result. Now, this code does not allocate memory for those pointers. I suppose that their allocation is made by xgboost.
Also, my code uses this pattern many times and works well.
My doubt is how to dispose of the memory used by those pointers. If I try to get free with the standard free call, I get a twice-free or a segfault.
The code I am improving seems correct and robust, but I am intrigued by this issue.
Some explanation?

My doubt is how to dispose of the memory used by those pointers -- That should be documented by the API you are using.  You simply can't make up your own way to deallocate the memory.

And this where making a C++ wrapper could be useful.  In C++ your api should return a std::unique_ptr if the client needs to take over ownership.  In that respect C++ is much more clear than C++.  Personal opinion : In/out parameters are never all that great

Looking at the documentation it says to copy the out_shape and out_result before use, which would indicate to me that it uses an internal buffer with static storage duration, and so those pointers should not be freed.  That's just a guess though; the documentation isn't very clear on the subject.

Looking at the code, it looks like it uses thread local storage owned by the object referenced by the BoosterHandle you pass, so when you XGBoosterFree that handle it should clean up that storage as well.

@MilesBudnek Yes, probably an internal buffer, but probably not with static storage duration. Seems to be mostly a bunch of std::vectors.
